# Find VAT numbers of length 11 after a word in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text a="VAT number 12345678901 mobile number 34567890234" I want to find only the number corresponding to a VAT number made up of 11 numbers (ie 12345678901) and I don't want to find 34567890234.

the regex I use is:

```
rgx = "(?<!\d)\d{11}(?!\d)"
```

but `re.findall(rg, a)` gives me both `34567890234` and `12345678901`.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In the precise string `a="VAT number 12345678901 mobile number 34567890234"`, this would look for 11 digits followed by a space and the word `mobile` but only return the digits. `rgx = "\d{11}(?=\smobile)"`

There are a lot of browser driven regular expression creators out there and they are great resource for learning.

Your original expression uses negative look around expressions `(?<\d)` and `(?!\d)`, they are not supported in all aspects so **I tend to avoid them**. Additionally, in terms of language structure, detecting the presence of something is generally more precise than the absence of something. Like if someone asks you what you want to drink and you reply "not poison" but you want a soda; you are less likely to get a soda.

So positive look around expressions will be more robust `(?=abc)` and `(?<abc)`

Comment: if, afther the second number there are a lot of word so a space?

Comment: @mememe I just added an edit that would work as long as the first number is followed by a space and the word mobile. Google the phrase 'regular expression generator' and a lot of helpful things come up.

Comment: I want only the 11 number after the word VAT number.. how can i find it?

Comment: You would employ a positive lookaround expression such as '(?<=(VAT\snumber\s))\d{11}'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(?:VAT\s*number\s*)(\d{11})\s+
```

this not capturing block : `(?:VAT\s*number\s*)` ensure to search the number after.

this block :
`(\d{11})\s+`
capture the VAT number only if it consists of 11 digits.